# Injecting DLL into process from embedded resources

Tags: c#, dll, code-injection

Right now i have a DLL written on C++, which injected through simple C# LoadLibraryA injector. DLL is extracted right before injecting from resources to my hdd... but how to inject it in process right from resources without extracting?

Comment: into your process, or into another process? and i think you can't use anything directly from the resources without extracting. You could encode your dll in a Base64 String and then load it from a stream.

Comment: Into another process.

Answer (score 0):

No way to do what you want. Method LoadLibrary for loading unmanaged dll has no overloads and has one argument - path to library. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14158846/load-library-module-from-memory) contains simple example of loading dll from memory, but it very simple.

Comment: I mean, maybe there is some other injection method exist? I've founded almost what i need, but it's doesn't working. Injector have stucked and my target application lagging without any activity of my DLL. Link to library i've founded - http://www.mpgh.net/forum/showthread.php?t=531732